# Can I use ‘could’ to talk about Simple Future Tense?

Tags: grammar, future-tense

As far as I know there are two ways to use the simple future tense: we can use either “will” or “be going to”.

For example:

> It will rain tomorrow( it’s going to rain tomorrow)

> It could rain tomorrow (it’s possible that it will rain tomorrow)

“It could rain tomorrow” isn’t the simple future tense?

Answer (score 1):

> It could rain tomorrow.

This isn't simple future tense. "Could" here expresses a possible future.

Similarly, you can use "may":

> It may rain tomorrow.

... which is also an expression of possibility, not future simple.